# How to set up a MANET using B.A.T.M.A.N-adv

Tags: networking, 23.04, adhoc

i want to set up a mobile ad hoc network (MANET) using a wifi usb

airmon-ng output

```
PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlp4s0      mt7921e     MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter

phy4    wlx6c5ab00f0b90 rtl8821au   TP-Link AC600 wireless Realtek RTL8811AU [Archer T2U Nano]
```

( the second one)

and let connections connect to wifi viaw the first one